# Как реализовать несколько галерей на сайте Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Суть в том, что мне нужно для сайта на Битриксе реализовать "множественные галереи". Я имею ввиду, дать пользователю возможность сначала заполнить одну, потом добавить и заполнить вторую и так до бесконечности, а потом вставить это, например, в детальное описание.
Это вообще возможно?: )
И если да, не могли бы дать наводку, где почитать, где узнать подробнее про такую реализацию, потому что я даже не могу правильно сформировать свою мысль, чтобы гугл дал мне то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут вариантов масса (зависит от деталей, редакции битрикс и т.п.).... Например элемент инфоблока это отдельная галерея.у него есть свойство привязка к пользователю и множественное картинки. У той сущности к которой их надо прикреплять на детальной странице.Есть множественное свойство привязки к элементам раздела (галереи)...